lambda comparing a timestamp to all timestamps from another column within a group
I'm having trouble with specifying a lambda function. I would like to have something like the lambda below, but not quite. The code should compare a rejected_time with any paid_out_time within the group and return True, if a rejected_time occurs within 5 minutes after any paid_out_time.
f = lambda x: ((x['rejected_time'].dropna() - x['paid_out_time'].dropna()).between(pd.Timedelta(0), pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)))
Using x['paid_out_time'].min() generates about 100k True values, but dropping .min() results in dramatic reduction. I can't figure out how to use all paid_out_times in the comparison against a row-wise rejected_time and see if the rejected time occurs 0-5minutes after the paid_out_time.
I've been testing this code:
cols = ['paid_out_time', 'rejected_time']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

f = lambda x: ((x['rejected_time'].dropna() - x['paid_out_time'].dropna().min()).between(pd.Timedelta(0), pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)))

df['paid_out_auto_rejection'] = df.groupby('personal_id', group_keys=False).apply(f).astype(int)

Here's some test data:



personal_id
application_id
rejected_time
paid_out_time
expected




26A
1ab
2022-09-12 09:20:40.592
NaT
1


26A
1ab
2022-08-23 07:40:03.447463
NaT
0


26A
1ab
2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392
NaT
1


26A
1ab
2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392
NaT
1


26A
1ab
2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000
2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392
1


26A
1ab
2022-09-02 18:33:42.226000
NaT
0


26A
8f0
2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000
NaT
1


26A
8f0
2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000
NaT
1


26A
8f0
NaT
2022-09-12 09:20:40.592
0


26A
8f0
2022-09-12 09:21:08.604000
NaT
1


26A
8f0
2022-09-22 08:27:45.693060
NaT
0




EDIT: For improve performance is used merge_asof with tolerance parameter:
cols = ['paid_out_time', 'rejected_time']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

df1 = df[['personal_id','application_id','rejected_time']].reset_index()
df2 = df[['personal_id','application_id','paid_out_time']]

df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('rejected_time').dropna(subset=['rejected_time']), 
                   df2.sort_values('paid_out_time').dropna(subset=['paid_out_time']), 
                   left_on='rejected_time', 
                   right_on='paid_out_time',
                   by='personal_id',
                   direction="nearest",
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5Min")
                   ).set_index('index')

df['new'] = (df3['rejected_time'].sub(df3['paid_out_time']).notna()
                                 .reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0)
                                 .astype(int))


print (df)
   personal_id application_id              rejected_time  \
0         26A            1ab  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
1         26A            1ab  2022-08-23 07:40:03.447463   
2         26A            1ab  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392   
3         26A            1ab  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392   
4         26A            1ab  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
5         26A            1ab  2022-09-02 18:33:42.226000   
6         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
7         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
8         26A            8f0                         NaT   
9         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:21:08.604000   
10        26A            8f0  2022-09-22 08:27:45.693060   

                paid_out_time  new  
0                         NaT    1  
1                         NaT    0  
2                         NaT    1  
3                         NaT    1  
4  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392    1  
5                         NaT    0  
6                         NaT    1  
7                         NaT    1  
8  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000    0  
9                         NaT    1  
10                        NaT    0  

If need compare all non missing values use numpy broadcasting:
cols = ['paid_out_time', 'rejected_time']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')


def f(x):
    
    arr = x['rejected_time'].dropna().to_numpy() - 
                      x['paid_out_time'].dropna().to_numpy()[:, None]
    m = (arr >= pd.Timedelta(0)) & (arr <= pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))
    
    x.loc[x['rejected_time'].notna(), 'new'] = np.any(m, axis=0)
    return x
out = (df.groupby('personal_id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
          .fillna({'new':False}).astype({'new':int}))


print (out)
   personal_id application_id              rejected_time  \
0         26A            1ab  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
1         26A            1ab  2022-08-23 07:40:03.447463   
2         26A            1ab  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392   
3         26A            1ab  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392   
4         26A            1ab  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
5         26A            1ab  2022-09-02 18:33:42.226000   
6         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
7         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000   
8         26A            8f0                         NaT   
9         26A            8f0  2022-09-12 09:21:08.604000   
10        26A            8f0  2022-09-22 08:27:45.693060   

                paid_out_time  new  
0                         NaT    1  
1                         NaT    0  
2                         NaT    1  
3                         NaT    1  
4  2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392    1  
5                         NaT    0  
6                         NaT    1  
7                         NaT    1  
8  2022-09-12 09:20:40.592000    0  
9                         NaT    1  
10                        NaT    0  


Here's what new should be:
new
1
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
1
0.
First row is within 5min after the second paid_out_time (2022-09-12 09:20:40.592).
Third row is within 5min after the first paid_out_time (2022-08-02 23:16:59.545392)

@AlexGünsberg - I see, added <= and >= for comparing instead < and >

I got after 4min of runtime ValueError: Columns must be the same length as key. The data I'm working with is massive.

@AlexGünsberg - Yes, numpy broadcasting need a lot of memory, added new solution with merge_asof, it should be faster.

Wow! That was elegant! It took 6s 84ms to run it and it works. Thanks!
